# How to add videos in listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show images and videos in listview i am able show images but i want to show video also please help me . I want to create app like instagram here is my code for the video.

```
class mydynamic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _mydynamicState createState() => _mydynamicState();
 }

class _mydynamicState extends State<mydynamic> {
 List<String> urls = [
"https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4",
"https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4",
"https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4"
];

VideoPlayerController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
_ controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
    'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
  ..initialize().then((_) {
    setState(() {});
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(title: Text("Adas")),
  body: Center(
    child: _controller.value.initialized
        ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          )
        : Container(),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _controller.value.isPlaying
            ? _controller.pause()
            : _controller.play();
      });
    },
    child: Icon(
      _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
    ),
  ),
);
}
 @override
  void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _controller.dispose();
}
}
```

I have tried this above example which is working fine but i am not able to apply the logic for putting the videos in listview please any solution for this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListView.Builder` with `List<VideoPlayerController>` of video controllers

```
class _mydynamicState extends State<mydynamic> {
  List<String> urls = [
    "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4",
    "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4",
    "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4"
  ];

  List<VideoPlayerController> _controllers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    urls.forEach((element) {
      _controllers.add(VideoPlayerController.network(element));
    });
  }

  void _playVideos() {
    _controllers.forEach((controller) {
      controller
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          setState(() {});
        });
      controller.value.isPlaying ? controller.pause() : controller.play();
    });
  }

  bool isVideosPlaying() {
    for (VideoPlayerController controller in _controllers) {
      if (controller.value.isPlaying) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: Text("Adas")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          VideoPlayerController controller = _controllers[index];
          print(controller.value.isPlaying);
          return Container(
            child: controller.value.initialized
                ? AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(controller),
                  )
                : Container(),
          );
        },
        itemCount: urls.length,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _playVideos();
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          isVideosPlaying() ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controllers.forEach((controller) {
      controller.dispose();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to play all videos at the same time?

Comment: It is working only when play the videos one time after when i play the video it shows black screen and after i play the video again it show blank screen

Comment: No when i click on the particular video then after have to that video

Comment: Not working giving many errors in terminal only first time the videos are playing after that not working giving black screen

Comment: you have only one fab button from where you want to start/stop the video, so its difficult to start/stop video with one button, may  be you can start video on click of video & then stop it with fab button

Comment: please check this link i want same but when we scroll the video have to stop playing [link](https://youtu.be/XP-4BiWsuaQ)

Comment: why you are not following that video then? its easy

Comment: yes i followed but the problem is that it is giving me error for dispose when is use to dispose to dispose the controller it is giving me error like this   'A Videoplayrcontroller was used after being dispose Onece you have called dispose() on controller it can no longer be used'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216825/discussion-between-prototype86-and-jitsm555).